# How to load two models in the same controller with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been searching on Internet and on stackoverflow, but i didn't find a solution, or it wasn't the same problem.

I need to load two models in the same controller, and in the same function. One is "model_membre" and the other "model_annonce". It's the name of the class, the file, and the object.

Individually, they work very good, i can access to properties and methods, but when I'm loading the two models, I can't access to the second, regardless of how I load it (autoload, `$this->load->model('model_name')`, `$this->load->model('model_name', 'object_name')`).

I simplified to a "test" controller, to see if it was not another part of my code that made the problem :

```
    public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('model_membre', 'membre');
    $this->load->model('model_annonce', 'annonce');
    $liste = $this->annonce->listerEspeces();
    $membre = $this->membre->obtenirMembre(1);
}
```

I tried to changer the order, and the 2nd loaded never works. I get this message :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Test::$annonce
>   Filename: controllers/test.php
>   Line Number: 15

> Fatal error: Call to a member function listerEspeces() on a non-object in /homez.604/animalix/beta/application/controllers/test.php on line 15

Comment: Are you sure that your model is not stored in subfolder 
for example  models->subfolder->your_model

Comment: No, both are stored in /application/models/model_name.php :/ If not, they would not be loaded and work individually

Comment: What happens when you ONLY load ``model_annonce`` ? Does it work properly then?

Comment: Have you tried without the second param in `load->model` and calling `$this->model_annonce->listerEspeces()`?

Comment: Also, if you're using `__construct()` in any of your models, remember to add `parent::__construct()` in your `__construct()` method which may be causing this error.

Comment: @ashiina If I load only one, model_annonce or model_membre, it works perfectly. The problem is when I load another model, it looks like if it wasn't loaded, i have the same error when I try to access to a method that exists, and when I try to access to a method that does'nt exist ( $this->jkqzsjgmjg->jdljlhgf(); ). When I load the model, I don't have any error, $this->load->model('unexisting_model'); will return an error, not my calling.

Comment: @StevenLu Yes I have my constructors and they call to the parent : public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
 }. And yes I tried to load it with an object name, without, and from the autoload.php !

Comment: May be this link would help you: <br />
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/213833/

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot, I thaught my models were extending CI_Model, and not, they were extending CI_Controller!! Now it works perfectly!!

Comment: Extending CI_controller instead of CI_Model is pretty bad mistake :)

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following way...

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->load->model(array('membre','annonce'));
    $liste = $this->annonce->listerEspeces();
    $membre = $this->membre->obtenirMembre(1);
}
```

Comment: I tried the following without success, the same error, call to a member function listerEspeces() on a non-object. [code]public function index()
 {
  $this->load->model(array('model_membre', 'model_annonce'));
  $liste = $this->model_annonce->listerEspeces();
  $membre = $this->model_membre->obtenirMembre(1);
 }[/code]

Comment: @OwNAkS - then your error might be coming from another part of your code.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan It is not possible because I made a controller just for testing, empty, with just the constructor, and the function written above. I dont have any models loaded in my autoload.php.

Comment: then try loading both models from autoload :)

Answer (score 2):

The models should extend CI_Model and not CI_Controller! This was the source of the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much i almost killed myself